# Webservice to open external program when clicking link in Power BI

Tags: web-services, url, hyperlink, powerbi

as Microsoft Power BI only allows to add hyperlinks of the following types

- mailto
- News
- Telnet
- FTP
- File

I was thinking, if it could be possible to write a small webservice (ideally under IIS), which redirects an URL to let open a different hyperlink type.

The thing is, that I made a Power BI report, which reads from a Microsoft SQL server instance, which is running behind a propriertary Windows native CRM software.
What I want to achieve is to get back to the software, as soon as e.g. a customer number in the Power BI dashboard is clicked (made clickable using the conditional formatting).

It is already possible to open the dataset using an URL by entering something like:

`<applicationname>:OpenAddress?Number=12345` in my Webbrowser.

So as Power BI does not let me add this syntax directly, I thought it could be possible to have a link like `http://localhost:8080/OpenAddress?Number=12345` which redirects to the above individual hyperlink type.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Regards
Lars

Answer (score 1):

After a while of thinking I solved this issue using some simple lines of Javascript:

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
parameter = params.get('number');

finalurl = "<applicationname>:OpenAddress?number=" + parameter;

window.location.replace(finalurl);
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where in Power BI did you add this script? Thanks.

Comment: @Sikander No, I did not directly added the script to Power BI. I created a HTML file (convert.html) with the script and put it onto a webserver. Afterwards I added a new column to my data in Power BI with ````ejURL2 = "<webserver>/convert.html?number="&'Datatable'[Number]```` which is assigned to the column in the report using "Conditional Formatting -> WebURL".